# autospec with cucumber in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cucumber, bdd

I have cucumber features working fine and rspec spec working fine i can run both cucumber features and spec spec and they all work but now im looking at getting autospec to run but running does the produces the following

Warning: $KCODE is NONE.
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.3.90/lib/cucumber/step_definition.rb:100: warning: method redefined; discarding old regexp
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/treetop-1.2.6/lib/treetop/ruby_extensions/string.rb:31: warning: method redefined; discarding old indent
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/treetop-1.2.6/lib/treetop/compiler/node_classes/character_class.rb:13: warning: useless use of a literal in void context
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/treetop-1.2.6/lib/treetop/compiler.rb:5: warning: global variable `$exclude_metagrammar' not initialized
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/treetop-1.2.6/lib/treetop/compiler/metagrammar.rb:232: warning: method redefined; discarding old space
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/treetop-1.2.6/lib/treetop/compiler/metagrammar.rb:388: warning: method redefined; discarding old space
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/treetop-1.2.6/lib/treetop/compiler/metagrammar.rb:771: warning: method redefined; discarding old space
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/treetop-1.2.6/lib/treetop/compiler/metagrammar.rb:779: warning: method redefined; discarding old space
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.3.90/lib/cucumber/parser/feature.rb:28: warning: method redefined; discarding old white
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.3.90/lib/cucumber/parser/feature.rb:36: warning: method redefined; discarding old white
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.3.90/lib/cucumber/parser/feature.rb:679: warning: method redefined; discarding old white
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.3.90/lib/cucumber/parser/feature.rb:687: warning: method redefined; discarding old white
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.3.90/lib/cucumber/parser/feature.rb:813: warning: method redefined; discarding old white
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.3.90/lib/cucumber/parser/feature.rb:825: warning: method redefined; discarding old white
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/blank.rb:49: warning: method redefined; discarding old blank?

im running AUTOFEATURE=true autospec

is there a solution

cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had something bad in the .autotest file so i cleared it out and everything works now

Answer (score 1):

```
$KCODE = 'U'
```

and put this in `.autotest` file